# Parent coordinate given a CCNode local coordinate

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Is there any cocos2d function that returns the parent coordinate given a node local coordinate? It must be quite a common use case, but I've not found any native cocos2d function. Is there any?

I guess it's something like this. NOTE, I haven't tested this one. ;)

```
-(CGPoint) nodeToParent: (CGPoint) localPoint
{
  CGFloat phi = -self.rotation * B2_pi / 180;
  return ccpAdd(self.position, ccpRotateByAngle(localPoint, ccp(0, 0), phi));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As m.ding said ... parent->ConvertToNodeSpace() .....

Here's explanation for you so you know when to do what ?

convertToWorldSpace(const CCPoint& nodePoint) converts on-node coords to SCREEN coordinates.
Lets we have layerA with anchor point and position (0,0) attached to screen and have a sprite on this layer at point (100, 100).
What will be SCREEN coords of sprite? - (100, 100)

Lets we moved layerA to point (- 50, - 20). What will be SCREEN coords of sprite? - (100 - 50, 100 - 20), i.e. (50, 80) - that's what convertToWorldSpace returns to us if we call layerA->convertToWorldSpace(ccp(100, 100)).

As for convertToWorldSpaceAR - will return the position relatevely to anchor point: so if our scene - root layer has AP (0.5f, 0.5f) - default, convertToWorldSpaceAR should return position relatively to screen center. I have used convertToNodeSpace

convertToNodeSpace(const CCPoint& worldPoint) - converts SCREEN coords to NODE's local. I.e. if for our example with moved layer call:
layerA->convertToNodeSpace(ccp(50, 80)) - that should return (100, 100) - our sprite on-node coords.

convertToNodeSpaceAR - the same logic as for convertToWorldSpaceAR

Comment: Assume ccNodeA is a child of ccNodeB which is a child of layerA. Then if I want to get ccNodeA coordinate ccp(50, 50) as a ccNodeB coordinate I need to go via screen coordinates: localNodeACoordAsNodeBCoord = [ccNodeB convertToNodeSpace [ccNodeA convertToWorldSpace: ccp(50, 50)]]. There's no easier way?

Answer (score 1):

assume your parent node is

```
CCSprite* parent;
```

you can use:

```
parent->convertToNodeSpace();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that

```
-(CGPoint) convertToWorldSpace:(CGPoint)pt
```

could do the trick, take a look [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_node.html#a3f43b7356576a39f137ff24960ced8f2).

Comment: Can it? I want to convert to parent coordinates. If I'm not completely wrong convertToWorldSpace converts to screen coordinates.

Comment: Have you tried it? For converting to screen coordinates I see a method which is called `convertToWindowSpace`.

Comment: Bad post above...

Yes, I think I've tried it a while ago.

You mean that convertToWorldSpace returns the coordinates in the coordinate system of its parent? And if N1 is child to N2 which is child to N3, then [N1 convertToWorldSpace ccp(1, 0)] returns a coordinate in N2's coordinate system?

I don't think so. How sure are you about this? If you're sure, maybe I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on the right track.  `[node position]` should give the position of the node in the parent's coordinate space, so if you have a local point that is offset from the `[node position]` then you need to do add the offset like you have done.  I'm not sure the `ccpRotateByAngle` is the right method to do that but you'll just have to test it and find out!